# second order Taylor expansion of logdet(X)

Tags: taylor-expansion

I was reading the paper "Stationary Subspace Analysis as a
Generalized Eigenvalue Problem (ASSA)" and encountered the problem of formula derivation, ASSA changes the problem of solving the objective function in SSA into an eigenvalue problem. Equation (4) is the objective function in SSA. ASSA approximating the logdet() term in (4) with its second order Taylor expansion $\widetilde{f}$ . My question is how $\widetilde{f}(W,W_*)$ is written in the form (5).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB4Q9.png)